# How to force user to enter values again and again until input is OK - arithmetic calculator

Tags: python

I need your help. I am trying to learn Python (I am a complete junior) and the best way to learn it is by programming or coding. I made an arithmetic calculator but I want to take it to the next level where the user must enter correct values such as (+, -. *, /) If entering another value must be asked again to enter the correct value. And at the end of it all ask you if you want to continue using the calculator. But I've run out of ideas, please help.....!!!!!!

Here is the code:

```
def suma():

    number = int(input("Enter the number you want to study in the table: "))
    row = int(input("Until what number do you want to study the table: "))

    for i in range(1, row+1):
        print(number, operator, i, "=", number+i)


def resta():

    number = int(input("Enter the number you want to study in the table: "))
    row = int(input("Until what number do you want to study the table: "))

    for i in range(1, row+1):
        print(number, operator, i, "=", number-i)


def multx():

    number = int(input("Enter the number you want to study in the table: "))
    row = int(input("Until what number do you want to study the table: "))

    for i in range(1, row+1):
        print(number, operator, i, "=", number*i)


def div():

    number = int(input("Enter the number you want to study in the table: "))
    row = int(input("Until what number do you want to study the table: "))

    for i in range(1, row+1):
        print(number, operator, i, "=", number/i)


operator = input("Enter the table operator |+,-,*,/|: ")

if operator == "+":

    suma()

elif operator == "-":

    resta()

elif operator == "*":

    multx()

elif operator == "/":

    div()

else:

    print("Please type a valid operator |+,-,*,/|")  # RULES


Repeat = input("Would you like to do another Math (y/n): ").lower()

if Repeat == "y":

    main()

else:

    print()
    print("Keep learning..!!")
    print("Bye")
    exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or simpler you can do something like this too.

```
op = ""
allowed_operations = "+", "-", "*", "/", "//", "**"

while True:
    number = input("Enter the number you want to study in the table: ")
    row = input("Until what number do you want to study the table: ")
    while op not in allowed_operations:
        op = input(f"Enter the table operator {allowed_operations}: ")

    for i in range(1, int(row) + 1):
        print(number, op, i, "=", eval(f"{number} {op} {i}"))

    rep = input("Would you like to do another Math (y/n): ").lower()
    if rep == "n":
        break
```

Comment: Ali Aref.....

Excellent solution and very practical but I have an additional question with this solution (I am new to Python and on my way to learn). When I run the code it works correctly but when it asks again if you want to perform another calculation, it stays stuck in the operator that was entered in the beginning and does not ask you again what type of arithmetic operation you want to do. Could you help me with that? Thank you!

Comment: @MiguelRomanR. just add a `op=''` at the start of loop to fix the bug

Comment: @xcodz-dot  Thank you very much for your help. I hope one day I can help others like you do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can simply put things in a while loop and exit the while loop when required. Also exit is not something that you should be using (Some embeded python implementations does not support exit builtin function). To use exit function you need to import it from module `sys`. Here is the code put into while loop:

```py
def suma():

    number = int(input("Enter the number you want to study in the table: "))
    row = int(input("Until what number do you want to study the table: "))

    for i in range(1, row+1):
        print(number, operator, i, "=", number+i)


def resta():

    number = int(input("Enter the number you want to study in the table: "))
    row = int(input("Until what number do you want to study the table: "))

    for i in range(1, row+1):
        print(number, operator, i, "=", number-i)


def multx():

    number = int(input("Enter the number you want to study in the table: "))
    row = int(input("Until what number do you want to study the table: "))

    for i in range(1, row+1):
        print(number, operator, i, "=", number*i)


def div():

    number = int(input("Enter the number you want to study in the table: "))
    row = int(input("Until what number do you want to study the table: "))

    for i in range(1, row+1):
        print(number, operator, i, "=", number/i)


while True:
    operator = input("Enter the table operator |+,-,*,/|: ")

    if operator == "+":

        suma()

    elif operator == "-":

        resta()

    elif operator == "*":

        multx()

    elif operator == "/":

        div()

    else:

        print("Please type a valid operator |+,-,*,/|")  # RULES


    Repeat = input("Would you like to do another Math (y/n): ").lower()

    if Repeat != "y":
        print()
        print("Keep learning..!!")
        print("Bye")
        break
```

Comment: xcodz-dot; Thank you very much for your prompt reply. I only have one query about this solution. When an incorrect operator is entered, the code stops and does not give you the option to enter the operator again. Can this be corrected or changed? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By using `break` statement you can break out of the loop if the user enter `no`

Demo:

```
def suma():

    number = int(input("Enter the number you want to study in the table: "))
    row = int(input("Until what number do you want to study the table: "))

    for i in range(1, row+1):
        print(number, operator, i, "=", number+i)
def resta():

    number = int(input("Enter the number you want to study in the table: "))
    row = int(input("Until what number do you want to study the table: "))

    for i in range(1, row+1):
        print(number, operator, i, "=", number-i)


def multx():

    number = int(input("Enter the number you want to study in the table: "))
    row = int(input("Until what number do you want to study the table: "))

    for i in range(1, row+1):
        print(number, operator, i, "=", number*i)


def div():

    number = int(input("Enter the number you want to study in the table: "))
    row = int(input("Until what number do you want to study the table: "))

    for i in range(1, row+1):
        print(number, operator, i, "=", number/i)
    
while(True):

    operator = input("Enter the table operator |+,-,*,/|: ")
    
    if operator == "+":
    
        suma()
    
    elif operator == "-":
    
        resta()
    
    elif operator == "*":
    
        multx()
    
    elif operator == "/":
    
        div()
    
    else:
    
        print("Please type a valid operator |+,-,*,/|")  # RULES
    
    
    Repeat = input("Would you like to do another Math (y/n): ").lower()
    
    if Repeat == "n":
        break


print()
print("Keep learning..!!")
print("Bye")
exit()
```

Comment: Khageshwor;  Thank you very much for your prompt reply. I only have one query about this solution. When an incorrect operator is entered, the code stops and does not give you the option to enter the operator again. Can this be corrected or changed? Thank you!